# Cannot get XMPP vCard user search working properly version 21.12-1 ejabberd under Ubuntu 22.04.2 and LDAP to Active Directory

Tags: ejabberd, xmpp

I'm have tested with Swift and Gajim.  AD authentication integration works, but the vcard search fails when run from both Swift and Gajim but succeeds from the command line.  Gajim is from the nightly build from 6/11/2023   Any suggestions?

this works:

```
root@im:/etc/ejabberd# ejabberdctl get_vcard samsmith localhost FN
Sam Smith
```

The configuration is vanilla right out of the documentation here:

https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/ldap/#active-directory

Pigdin works but does not have vcard search in it that I can see.  It does work on searching for user info if you type in the userID but not for wildcard searches

All the other desktop XMPP clients I have tried seem to be old and use old SSL encryption and will not connect to ejabberd

Here's the relevant config:

```
auth_method: [ldap]
ldap_servers:
  - "dc1.example.com"
ldap_encrypt: none
ldap_base: "dc=example,dc=com"
ldap_rootdn: 'cn=Administrator,ou="Administrative Accounts",ou="Information Technology",ou=Administration,dc=example,dc=com'
ldap_password: "guessme"
ldap_uids: ["sAMAccountName"]
ldap_filter: "(objectClass=user)"
.
.
.
 mod_stream_mgmt:
    resend_on_timeout: if_offline
  mod_stun_disco: {}

  mod_vcard:
    search: true
    db_type: ldap
    ldap_vcard_map:
      NICKNAME: {"%u": []}
      GIVEN: {"%s": [givenName]}
      MIDDLE: {"%s": [initials]}
      FAMILY: {"%s": [sn]}
      FN: {"%s": [displayName]}
      EMAIL: {"%s": [mail]}
      ORGNAME: {"%s": [company]}
      ORGUNIT: {"%s": [department]}
      CTRY: {"%s": [c]}
      LOCALITY: {"%s": [l]}
      STREET: {"%s": [streetAddress]}
      REGION: {"%s": [st]}
      PCODE: {"%s": [postalCode]}
      TITLE: {"%s": [title]}
      URL: {"%s": [wWWHomePage]}
      DESC: {"%s": [description]}
      TEL: {"%s": [telephoneNumber]}
    ldap_search_fields:
      User: "%u"
      Name: givenName
      "Family Name": sn
      Email: mail
      Company: company
      Department: department
      Role: title
      Description: description
      Phone: telephoneNumber
    ldap_search_reported:
      "Full Name": FN
      Nickname: NICKNAME
      Email: EMAIL


  mod_vcard_xupdate: {}
  mod_version: {}

.
.

Here is the error I get when I try a search from Gajim for Windows clicking Accounts  Discover Services,  vCard User Search  vjud.im.example.com in the /var/log/ejabberd/error.log file

2023-06-11 21:22:27.776738+00:00 [info] <0.566.0>@ejabberd_c2s:bind/2:442 (tls|<0.566.0>) Opened c2s session for samsmith@im.example.com/gajim.LW3ZEHS3
2023-06-11 21:23:08.430561+00:00 [error] <0.566.0>@gen_iq_handler:process_iq/4:116 Failed to process iq:
#iq{
 id = <<"19500e8f-201c-461d-9021-eb5c2eb30f9d">>,type = set,lang = <<"en">>,
 from =
  #jid{
   user = <<"samsmith">>,server = <<"im.example.com">>,
   resource = <<"gajim.LW3ZEHS3">>,luser = <<"samsmith">>,
   lserver = <<"im.example.com">>,lresource = <<"gajim.LW3ZEHS3">>},
 to =
  #jid{
   user = <<>>,server = <<"vjud.im.example.com">>,resource = <<>>,luser = <<>>,
   lserver = <<"vjud.im.example.com">>,lresource = <<>>},
 sub_els =
  [#xmlel{
    name = <<"query">>,
    attrs = [{<<"xmlns">>,<<"jabber:iq:search">>}],
    children =
     [#xmlel{
       name = <<"x">>,
       attrs = [{<<"xmlns">>,<<"jabber:x:data">>},{<<"type">>,<<"submit">>}],
       children =
        [#xmlel{
          name = <<"title">>,attrs = [],
          children = [{xmlcdata,<<"Search users in vjud.im.example.com">>}]},
         #xmlel{
          name = <<"instructions">>,attrs = [],
          children =
           [{xmlcdata,
             <<"Fill in the form to search for any matching XMPP User (Add * to the end of field to match substring)">>}]},
         #xmlel{        
          name = <<"field">>,
          attrs =
           [{<<"var">>,<<"%u">>},
            {<<"type">>,<<"text-single">>},
            {<<"label">>,<<"User">>}],
          children =
           [#xmlel{
             name = <<"value">>,attrs = [],
             children = [{xmlcdata,<<"samsmith*">>}]}]},
         #xmlel{
          name = <<"field">>,
          attrs =
           [{<<"var">>,<<"givenName">>},
            {<<"type">>,<<"text-single">>},
            {<<"label">>,<<"Name">>}],
          children = []},
         #xmlel{
          name = <<"field">>,
          attrs =
           [{<<"var">>,<<"sn">>},
            {<<"type">>,<<"text-single">>},
            {<<"label">>,<<"Family Name">>}],
          children = []},
         #xmlel{
          name = <<"field">>,
          attrs =
           [{<<"var">>,<<"mail">>},
            {<<"type">>,<<"text-single">>},
            {<<"label">>,<<"Email">>}],
          children = []},
         #xmlel{
          name = <<"field">>,
          attrs =
           [{<<"var">>,<<"company">>},
            {<<"type">>,<<"text-single">>},
            {<<"label">>,<<"Company">>}],
          children = []},
         #xmlel{
          name = <<"field">>,
          attrs =
           [{<<"var">>,<<"department">>},
            {<<"type">>,<<"text-single">>},
            {<<"label">>,<<"Department">>}],
          children = []},
         #xmlel{
          name = <<"field">>,
          attrs =
           [{<<"var">>,<<"title">>},
            {<<"type">>,<<"text-single">>},
            {<<"label">>,<<"Role">>}],
          children = []},
         #xmlel{
          name = <<"field">>,
          attrs =
           [{<<"var">>,<<"description">>},
            {<<"type">>,<<"text-single">>},
            {<<"label">>,<<"Description">>}],
          children = []},
         #xmlel{
          name = <<"field">>,
          attrs =
           [{<<"var">>,<<"telephoneNumber">>},
            {<<"type">>,<<"text-single">>},
            {<<"label">>,<<"Phone">>}],
          children = []}]}]}],
 meta = #{ip => {0,0,0,0,0,65535,44048,65067}}}
** exception error: no function clause matching
                  eldap_utils:'-make_filter/2-fun-1-'({<<"givenName">>,[]}) (eldap_utils.erl, line 114)
   in function  lists:flatmap/2 (lists.erl, line 1254)
   in call from lists:flatmap/2 (lists.erl, line 1254)
   in call from eldap_utils:make_filter/2 (eldap_utils.erl, line 113)
   in call from mod_vcard_ldap:search/4 (mod_vcard_ldap.erl, line 124)
   in call from mod_vcard:search_result/4 (mod_vcard.erl, line 483)
   in call from mod_vcard:process_search/1 (mod_vcard.erl, line 264)
   in call from gen_iq_handler:process_iq/3 (gen_iq_handler.erl, line 131)
```